# MATCH_PARENT/Horizontal padding pixel difference between XML and programmatically generated buttons

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement two simple buttons, one via the Design/XML and the other one programmatically.
I cannot understand why is there a left and right padding difference between the grey, programmatically generated button "Make Message" and the XML designed one "Make Invisibile"(red)?

[Screenshot Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HMMg.png)

XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_makeInvisible"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#E91E63"
        android:text="Make Invisibile"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonInvisible, buttonMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Invisible button found via findViewById method
        buttonInvisible = findViewById(R.id.button_makeInvisible);
        buttonInvisible.setOnClickListener(this); //waits for click

        //Implement Message Button programatically
        buttonMessage = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        buttonMessage.setId(View.generateViewId());

        //Define properties of the button
        buttonMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        buttonMessage.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        buttonMessage.setText("Make Message");
        buttonMessage.setOnClickListener(this); //waits for click

        //Define relative layout parameters
        ConstraintLayout relLayout = findViewById(R.id.relLayout);
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams param = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relLayout.addView(buttonMessage, param);

        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(relLayout);
        set.connect(buttonMessage.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP, buttonInvisible.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,50);
        //TODO: Adjust the horizontal padding for buttonMessage to be exactly as buttonInvisible
        set.applyTo(relLayout);
    }
```

Comment: Because they are using different styles. Which app theme are you using?

Comment: I am not using any App theme,, just an empty layout on which I try to create these two buttons. What style difference between the two implementations did you notice that you think impacts the padding?

Comment: Does the application or the activity use a theme (in the manifest) ?

Comment: It uses: android:theme="@style/AppTheme">